# How are u'123' or U'\n\t' or L'abc' integer constants in c?

Tags: c

While making a compiler for C language, I was looking for its grammar. I stumbled upon [ANSI C Grammar (Lex)](http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l-2011.html#check_type). There I found the following regular expression (RE):

```
{CP}?"'"([^'\\\n]|{ES})+"'"     { return I_CONSTANT; }
```

where CP and ES are as follows

```
CP  (u|U|L)
ES  (\\(['"\?\\abfnrtv]|[0-7]{1,3}|x[a-fA-F0-9]+))
```

I understand that ES is RE for escape sequence.

If I understand the regular expression correctly then, `u'123'` or `U'\n\t'` or `L'abc'` are valid `I_CONSTANT`s.

I wrote the following small program to see what constant values they represent.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%d %d %d\n", u'123', U'\n\t', L'abc');
    return 0;
}
```

This gave the following output.

51 9 99

I deciphered that they represent the ASCII value of the right-most character inside single quotes.
However, what I fail to understand is the use and importance of this kind of integer constant.

Comment: I think it doesn't mean they are valid, only that they pass lexical analysis.

Comment: But they compile successfully (using gcc) and run without errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are multicharacter literals, and their value is implementation-defined.

From C11 6.4.4.4 p10-11:

> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is implementation-deﬁned.

...

> The value of a wide character constant containing more than one multibyte character or a single multibyte character that maps to multiple members of the extended execution character set, or containing a multibyte character or escape sequence not represented in the extended execution character set, is implementation-deﬁned.

From your testing, it looks like GCC chooses to ignore all but the rightmost character on wide multicharacter literals. However, if you don't specify `L`, `u`, or `U`, GCC will combine the characters given as different bytes of the resulting integer, in an order depending on endianess. This behavior should not be relied on in portable code.